# Improve SQL: OR clause being used in AND clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a better way to write the following sql query

```
AND (
        product_return_date IS NULL
        OR product_return_date > SYSDATE
    )
```

Comment: Just use `OR` like you have done.

Comment: That is not a query, it's a condition

Comment: Putting functions (like `nvl` or `coalesce`) around `product_return_date` will prevent any index from being used. This sort of queries are usually more performant if you use a `union all` for each comparison

Comment: @HoneyBadger Oracle's optimizer may transform `or` condition into the `union all` by itself if it will find this useful. There's a hint for this: [`USE_CONCAT/NO_EXPAND`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-5A12BDC8-4CD1-448F-80BF-9F02653A3F94)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Example explain plans for different solutions  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72e8a262f42dfa2009cc4ced9db12ffd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when you write an `OR`, a `UNION ALL` of the the same queries with either of the conditions will have better performance than the `OR`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE product_return_date IS NULL
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE product_return_date > SYSDATE
```

Keep in mind, if you use `NVL` and there is an index on the product_return_date, it will prevent the use of the index.

Comment: thanks for your reply as I will be using the union all in a where clause will it go like the following: where id = (select id from table where product_return_date is null union all select id from table where product_return_date > sysdate)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'better' per se, but you could write this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(product_return_date, SYSDATE + 1) > SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert the statement thus:

```
AND nvl(product_return_date, SYSDATE+1) > SYSDATE;
```

In null case the date will be always greater than sysdate.

Thank you